# Corollary from Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: analysis, arzela-ascoli

We have proved Arzela-Ascoli Theorem as a family of functions in $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact metric space is relative compact iff it is equibounded and equicontinuous.

We’ve given a corollary for this. Every equicontinuous and equibounded sequence of $C(X)$ has an uniformly convergent subsequence.

I’ve seen the Rudin’s proof but there is some details like first countablity. Is there any basic and short way to obtain this corollary from the theorem we proved?

I’ve seen some proofs more and I’ve tried to do it but I’m not able to. If someone illuminate me on this shortly, I appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That’s just the “easy definition” of compactness (any sequence has a convergent subsequence) because $C(X)$ is a metric space.

Comment: @Mindlack closure of $f_n$ is compact thus all of them has a convergent subsequence. Equicontinuity and pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence. Is it a right approach?

Comment: No, I mean that $C(X)$ is a metric space with uniform convergence.

Comment: @Mindlack it has uniform continuity. Why should it have uniform convergence?

Comment: No. I mean that in the topology of $C(X)$ (which is metrizable), a sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ iff $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: The point you're missing @user519955 , is that, this family is relative compact, which means that this subset $\{ f_{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has a compact closure (relative to the topology of $C(X)$).

Comment: @ABP I’ve written same thing in my first comment. Closure of $f_n$ is compact it has at least one convergent subsequence because of compactness

Answer (score 2):

Note the followings:

1. $C(X)$ is equipped with the metric $d_{\sup}(f,g):=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)|$, and so, a sequence $(f_n)$ in $C(X)$ converges under the metric $d_{\sup}$ if and only if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly.
2. Arzela-Ascoli theorem tells that a subset $K$ of the metric space $(C(X),d_{\sup})$ is relatively compact if and only if $K$ is equibounded and equicontinuous.
3. A relatively compact sequence in a metric space has a convergent subsequence.

The the desired corollary is simply a combination of all these observations. Indeed, let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $C(X)$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\text{$(f_n)$ equibounded and equicontinuous} \\
&\Rightarrow \text{$(f_n)$ relative compact in $(C(X),d_{\sup})$} \tag{by A-A} \\
&\Rightarrow \text{$(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in $(C(X),d_{\sup})$} \tag{by 3}\\
&\Rightarrow \text{$(f_n)$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.} \tag{by 1}
\end{align*}